# Finding records having at least one upper-case character in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I'm trying to find in the database all records having records with Email field having at least one uppercase character.

```
Select * from `Profile` where Email REGEXP '[a-z0-9]*[A-Z]+[a-z0-9]*'
```

it's not even working when I want to ask for the first uppercase character only

```
Select * from `Profile` where Email REGEXP '^[A-Z].*' limit 10
```

In both cases I'm getting all records.

Comment: Use `BINARY` keyword to enable case sensitive regex search.

Comment: `REGEXP '[A-Z]' COLLATE utf8_bin` (if you are using `CHARACTER SET utf8`).